# visual studio 2010 team explorer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a project on vs 2010. I have tried to add project on windows server 2003 which has tfs 2010 installed. Later on I have switched to windows server 2008 and then installed tfs 2010 again. But I have changed server name.

Now, when I try to add project to tfs, I receive and error says that;

Team Foundation services are not available from server http://old server name:8080/tfs/. Technical information (for administrator): The remote name could not be resolved: 'old server name'

I have tried to add different projects but I havent received any errors. I am thinking problem is like, visual studio installed on my client computer has registered project with old server name and still tries the same server but team explorer can not find the server.

what shall I do?

PS: I am not tring to get my codes on old server. I did not use tfs, just wanted to learn it.

Comment: Have you tried clearing out all the workspaces?  Shot in the dark.

Comment: No I havent, I do not know how to do it either. But I will look for how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the message when you open Visual Studio then you need to go to Team Explorer and click the "Connect to Team Project" button, then click on the "servers" button and remove the old server. If you need to you can also add the new server here.

If it's when you're opening the solution then you need to remove the Source Control bindings

open the solution and then go to "File", "Source Control", "Change Source Control" this will open up a screen where you can Unbind the Projects and Solutions from the old server.

Comment: I get this error right after I try to add project solution to source control. What I exactly do is, I right-click on solution item, then choose "Add solution to source control" and I receive error I mentioned.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to add the solution from a folder on your system that is mapped to a workspace on the old server. If so move your solution to another folder on your hard drive, open it and try and add it again. If that doesn't work then try changing the server mapping in visual studio

Comment: yes, and changing folder works. but i dont want to change folder. I deleted workspace and added new one. Doing this also unbinded solution from source control.

Comment: I think it better after you install the new Server to delete your work space and make a new one for each client